# PDF Crowd API borders in PDF pages

Tags: html, css, pdf

Is there any way to apply a border of multipage pdf using PDF Crowd API.
I have spent half day searching it what I found is there is way to apply border via body tag. http://pdfcrowd.com/forums/read.php?3,1181
It is working well for one page PDF file.
What my problem is I have multipaged PDF file so by apply border on body tag is not working in that case.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: check out this blog http://pdfcrowd.com/blog/2011/03/18/create-html-footer-and-header-in-pdf.html it only sets the width of the page and puts a header and footer line across but it's close!! if you could just color the vertical margin!! this is the result http://pdfcrowd.com/blog/static/images/header-footer/result.pdf

Comment: I have tried with no luck.

Comment: This is what the closest I get till yet
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz3mh289zp9clyf/RvNDL98VUB1284.pdf?dl=0

Any help plz

Comment: yeah I know there is spacing issue in pdf crowd. I thinks you need to add/remove page breaks(a css property) for particular page element so border gets extended to next page.